# How does Quartus pin planner know about voltage in each I/O bank?

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus

It is possible to specify a range of I/O standard options in Quartus pin planner. I am trying to understand a few things:

1. How does Quartus know what voltage is supplied to each bank?
2. Why does Quartus give a long list of I/O standards for each pin and not limit them based on the supply voltage for that specific I/O bank?

Also,

3. What is the difference between "3.3V LVTTL" and "3.3V LVTTL (default)" in the pin planner?

Comment: I believe your question #1 answers #2.

Comment: 3 or '(default)' just means that it is not specified explicitly and it is implied.  If you go to the configuration file and set the voltage, it will not show as 'default'.  The configuration is typically '.qsf';  this type of information seems to change release-to-release and any information on the internet is often outdated.  It is difficult to change the voltages in the pin planner as it will complain that the banks are locking them.  Ie, you can not change them all at once in the GUI.  The QSF is a TCL file, like SDC, but Quartus modifies it during compiles so not revision control friendly.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't know. The Pin Planner is a variant of the more generic Assignment Editor, all it generates are additional constraints on the Fitter.

During compilation, the Fitter will tell you whether it can find a solution that fulfills all your constraints.

If you have Location assignments, then that is a pretty strict constraint, and if the Fitter cannot find a valid configuration, compilation fails.

If you have I/O Standard assignments, the Fitter will arrange pins so that the standard can be implemented, and then it will tell you what supply voltage is required for each bank.

The "(default)" setting removes the I/O Standard assignment for the pin from the list of assignments in the project file, the Fitter will then apply the project-wide default to the pin. If you change the default, it will be applied to any pin that is currently set to the "(default)" setting.

You'd normally create I/O standard assignments first, compile, and then refine from the generated configuration. That's why there is a read-only column "fitter location": this is what the fitter suggested, so if you start assigning pins but paint yourself into a corner, you can still see what it came up with.